# Realm object server not starting - IOS

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I am working with realm db with swift(IOS) when i try to start off the object server it provides me below error on terminal :

[image]

I could not find the similar error for object server , most of answer say this error occur while importing realm into IOS but i had not got that error , actually error occur while i start off object.server.command script for start server

Any help or reference to this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you change the configuration file? This error sound like it's trying to bind against an unknown hostname.

Comment: @teotwaki no i didnt changed anything in configuration file it is as it is when i downloaded bundle of realm

Comment: @Diva-MyMasterPeice Can you re-download latest RMP and re-try it?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that ipv6 is disabled on your machine. The default configuration uses `::` as the listen address for the http proxy, you can try to change that to `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1`.

here: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/blob/master/sample-configuration/ros-linux-configuration.yml#L161